# Set focus to hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, focus

How can I set focus to a hyperlink in asp.net? My hyperlink is in a repeater, and I want the item that is clicked to have focus.

**Edit**
This shows a lot of thumbnails. I want the thumbnail that is clicked to get focus.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="FileRepeater" runat="server" > 
<ItemTemplate> 
<asp:Image ID="Image" runat="server" />
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#"Default.aspx?image=" +  
Eval("Name") %>' ImageUrl='<%#"Content/Thumbnails/" + Eval("Name") %>'>  
HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate> 
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want the hyperlink to submit a form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to an ASP.NET `LinkButton` being able to submit a form, this is not possible.

A `LinkButton` renders as a hyperlink, and cannot submit forms.

I find `LinkButton` controls in general to be bad practice since these use javascript to be actioned, and don't have any functionality when javascript is disabled.

---

Your best option would be to use an ASP.NET `Button` and then style this to look like a hyper link.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a better method of doing this. This will work. I wrapped the hyperlink in a span. Once you click the hyperlink, the query string will be like

```
  Default.aspx?image=value
```

So on the document load, we are getting the paramter value and applying the style for the corresponding span to highlight.

```
<span class='<%#Eval("Name")%>'>
    <asp:HyperLinkID="HyperLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#"Default.aspx?image="+Eval("Name")%>'
    ImageUrl='<%#"Content/Thumbnails/" + Eval("Name") %>'>HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {           
        var myhlspan = getURLParameter("image");
       if (myhlspan != null) {
            $("." + myhlspan).css("border","3px solid yellow");
        }
    });
    function getURLParameter(name) {
       return decodeURI((RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search) || [,null])[1]);
    }

</script>
```